# How can family symmetries explain the 3 generations and their mixing?

Tags: beyond-the-standard-model

I recently read several papers (e.q. this one http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1340 ) about the usage of discrete, additional symmetries that can be used to explain the PMNS and/or CKM matrices. Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand the idea behind such lines of thought.

How can, for example, $A_4$ explain the numbers inside the PMNS matrix?

Comment: Please give more precise contexts. *What* papers, what is $A_4$ (I could guess it, but please state it)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I edited the question